# What is the best way to get rid of no-param-reassign error (eslint)?

Tags: javascript, eslint

I'm currently trying out eslint on this code and ran into an error (see screenshot). I'm not sure of what is the best way to get rid of the error.

code snippet:

```
let pathFor = ( path, view ) => {
  if ( path.hash ) {
    view = path;
    path = view.hash.route;
    delete view.hash.route;
  }
```

attempt to get rid of error (which works but not sure if it's the best way):

```
let pathFor = ( pathData, viewData ) => {
  if ( pathData.hash ) {
    view = pathData;
    path = view.hash.route;
    delete view.hash.route;
  }
```

Here is the screenshot of eslinting in sublime

[image]

Comment: what exactly is this function trying to accomplish?  It looks like you are passing in two values, then using one to overwrite the other?

Comment: @Jonah Williams oh sorry, I have edited it. This code snippet is something I just copy/paste from a boilerplate. I'm just practicing eslinting since it's new to me. I just want to know the best way to approach no-param-reassign.

Comment: Add `"no-param-reassign": 0` to your `.eslintrc` file. Otherwise your updated code is fine and better.

Comment: In your revised version, `view` and `path` are not declared anywhere. If they don't exist in higher scope that will be an error.

Comment: @AndyRay This article llustrates how important it is to not reassign function arguments. http://spin.atomicobject.com/2011/04/10/javascript-don-t-reassign-your-function-arguments/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lots of ways to do it. The linter is throwing at error because you're mutating a parameter, which can appear obfuscated to people reading your code, or cause other problems down the line. A more "functional style" of programming is basically what the linter is recommending (creating a new variable instead of mutating an old one), and probably rightly so. A method I've used in the past is with "Hungarian case":

```
let pathFor = (_path, _view) => {
  if (_path.hash) {
    view = _path;
    path = view.hash.route;
    delete view.hash.route;
  }
```

However, the little underscores can be arbitrary in their meaning depending on who's reading your code.

But, I think the way you have it is just fine. As Phil Karlton said:

> There are only two hard things in Computer Science: cache invalidation and naming things.

I think this question is more a question of "best naming practices" more than anything. If that's the case, I wouldn't waste too much mental energy on it.

Comment: Noted. Thanks for clarifying this issue :)

Comment: in your example `view` and `path` are never declared. That would probably make esLint act up again. Shouldn't it be `const view` ... `const path`

Comment: @RemEmber correct, I omitted the initial variable declarations (in theory they could declared in the function, but the assumption was that they were initialized outside of the function scope and "filled in" in the function body later on). Good catch.